# EF Core UPDATE ...FROM SELECT WHERE

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

How can I produce this query with EF Core SqlServer?

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Field1 = sil.Field1,
    Field2 = sil.Field2
FROM Table2 sil WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE sil.Field3= ''
    AND sil.Id1 = Table1.Id1
    AND sil.Id2 = Table1.Id2
    AND sil.Id3 != Table1.Id3
```

***IMPORTANT !***

I wanna produce it with *single* query (not query per row)

Comment: maybe try [ExecuteSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-3.1) ?

Comment: @GuruStron its not solution in my case

Comment: You can try [Entity Framework Core Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-batch-update), not sure they support the `FROM` syntax though.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no direct equivalent to an **UPDATE ... FROM** statement in EF.  Instead you would query your data set, update the entity models, and then push the updates back.

```
//  2 database select statements
var table1 = database.Table1.ToList();
var table2 = database.Table2.ToList();

//  in-memory processing.  no database involvement.
foreach(Entity1 t1record in table1) {
    var t2record = table2.Where(sil => ...).FirstOrDefault();
    if(null == t2record) { continue; }
    t1record.Field1 = t2record.Field1; // etc...
}
// push changes back to the database.  EFCore should do this as a single SQL statement
database.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: its bad. My problem is 10k records in table1 and about 100k records in table2. And i have some performance problems. thank you!

Comment: Mby some libraries can translate it?

Comment: Then don't use EF for that.  Use ADO.NET/System.Data.SqlClient.